# Colorbox: Calling colorbox.close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I'm working on a project that uses the velocity templating system, so the $ character is reserved, and cannot be used in javascript variable names.

As such, I have to prefix jQuery variables and methods with jQuery, rather than $, e.g. jQuery(document).ready(function() {}); as opposed to $(document)ready(function(){});

This is ordinarily fine, but in this case I am using colorbox.

My code to call colorbox works fine, and looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#addUser").colorbox({
        href:"add",
        width:"500px",
        onClosed: function (message) {
            dataTable.refresh(jQuery("#ajaxResult").text(message));
        }
    })

    ...
})
```

I have a link inside the colorbox that I want to attach the colorbox.close method to, but when I click the link, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method
>   'close' of undefined

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("a").click(function() {
        jQuery.colorbox.close("User added succesfully");
    });

    ...
})
```

**Can anybody tell me why I cannot close the colorbox?**

By the way, the X that comes with colorbox still works to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this for me was to store jQuery.colorbox as a variable in the global namespace. Yucky, but it works.

Here is what I put in the parent window:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    colorbox = jQuery.colorbox;

    ...
})
```

Then this is how I call it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("a").click(function() {
        colorbox.close("User added succesfully");
    });

    ...
})
```

Answer (score 6):

```
jQuery("#addUser").colorbox.close("User added succesfully");
```

Also, you should be able to use the `$` syntax for `jQuery` if you choose by [using external javascript files `<script type="text/javascript" src="my_script_file.js" />`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript) or [escaping the `$` like `\$`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Advanced_Issues:_Escaping_and_).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
jQuery().colorbox.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try writing jQuery.fn.colorbox.close("User added succesfully"); instead of jQuery.colorbox.close("User added succesfully");

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. The documentation says that's how your supposed to do it from within an iframe. This implementation does not use an iframe. I tried it anyway, and it didn't solve the problem. Thanks, though.