# JSP exception when I try to import static file

Tags: java, jsp, exception, jstl

I am trying to import javascript from a file into my jsp to be used as an in line script:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<script>
    <c:import url="/path/to/file.js" />
</script>
```

The above code works 99% of the time but I see a few errors like this in my tomcat logs:

```
Jun 20, 2013 1:25:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: 304 /path/to/file.js
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.acquireString(ImportSupport.java:329)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport.doEndTag(ImportSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.head.scripts_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fimport_005f0(scripts_jsp.java:182)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.common.head.scripts_jsp._jspService(scripts_jsp.java:85)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.game_jsp._jspService(game_jsp.java:181)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    .......
```

I found the code that throws the above exception in ImportSupport.java:

```
// disallow inappropriate response codes per JSTL spec
if (irw.getStatus() < 200 || irw.getStatus() > 299) {
    throw new JspTagException(irw.getStatus() + " " + stripSession(targetUrl));
}
```

So it looks like the servlet response code is 304.

The question is why? Is this a bug or am I missing something?

**Update:**

The problem seems to only occur if the incoming request has the If-Modified-Since header on

**Update 2:**

I solved the problem by removing the If-Modified-Since header from every request except for static files.

Comment: Try clearing the cache and try again .

Comment: Why not simply use: <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/file.js"></script>

Comment: @MickJ For performance reasons.

Comment: On the contrary you should get better performance by keeping it external instead of importing the content. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Spring MVC's ResourceHttpRequestHandler (configured with mvc:resources) to serve my static resources from /resources/* and it returns 304 on incoming requests that use the If-Modified-Since header. So when I include such a static resource with c:import and the incoming request has an  If-Modified-Since header I get the javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: 304 error.

I need dynamic including so @include isn't an option, and jsp:include produces an IllegalStateException when trying to include a URL handled by ResourceHttpRequestHandler. So I was left with writing my own include that reads from the file and writes it out in the JSP:

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourceLoader, org.springframework.core.io.Resource" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils" %>

<%
    String path = "/resources/fileName.html";
    ServletContextResourceLoader loader = new ServletContextResourceLoader(getServletConfig().getServletContext());
    Resource resource = loader.getResource(path);
    IOUtils.copy(contentResource.getInputStream(), pageContext.getOut());
 %>
```

Comment: That would work as well, especially if removing the if-modified-since isn't an option.

Comment: BTW - how did you remove the if-modified-since header from the request?

Comment: Yes, I only left it on for one directory from where static files are served to the clients browser.

Comment: How do you actually remove it? Just curious.

Comment: In Apache's http.conf

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding one "/" at the end url 
e.g
   Yours -- `<c:import url="/path/to/file.js"/>`
try with -- `<c:import url="/path/to/file.js/"/>`