# Syntax of Onchange event while creating a combo box in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<?php   
 echo "*Select Category<select name='category' id='category' onChange='ajax('fill.php', '', 'populate', 'post', '1')'><option value=''>--Please Select--</option><option value='1' >1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select>";
?>
```

What should come instead of codes(') for the arguements inside ajax function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backslashed quotes

```
onChange='ajax(\"fill.php\", \"\", \"populate\", \"post\", \"1\")'
```

HTML attributes should be in quotes, swap `'` and `"` in the code instead

```
echo '*Select Category<select name="category" id="category" onChange="ajax(\'fill.php\', \'\', \'populate\', \'post\', \'1\')"><option value="">--Please Select--</option><option value="1" >1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>';
```

To increase readability, use HEREDOC syntax

```
echo <<<STR
  *Select Category
  <select name="category" id="category" onChange="ajax('fill.php', '', 'populate', 'post', '1')">
    <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
STR;
```

Comment: But (") as far as i know dont work when we try to insert values for any attributes in php.

Comment: @user2126758 oops, forgot backslashes in the second one - see the update. Use the third one to avoid slashing issues.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
onChange=\"ajax('fill.php', '', 'populate', 'post', '1')\"
```

but it is even better and cleaner to assign the change event via jquery

```
$('#category').change(function(){
    ajax('fill.php', '', 'populate', 'post', '1');
});
```

if you dont want to use jquery you should put your javascript in a seperate function to have just a call inside your onchange:

```
onChange='callAjax()'

[...]

function callAjax() {
    ajax('fill.php', '', 'populate', 'post', '1');
}
```

Please read this thread in context [When should I use Inline vs. External Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript)

Comment: He has not marked the question as using jQuery or whatever other framework is using $, so the second option might not work for him.

Comment: it was just an advice. You can avoid much pain and work by using it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply alternate your inverted commas between double & single & escape where needed like so:

```
echo "*Select Category <select name='category' id='category' onChange=\"ajax('fill.php', '', 'populate', 'post', '1')\"><option value=''>--Please Select--</option><option value='1' >1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select>";
```

Specifically, changing:

```
onChange='...'
```

to

```
onChange=\"...\"
```