# How to change an html tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the text from a string into an HTML tag without moving to next page and display it.

```
<body>
<div>
    <label id="lbl1">Label </label>
    <button id="btn1" onclick="display()">Click </button>
    <script>
    function display() {
        var str="Hello World";
        document.write(str);
    }
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

How do I edit the contents of the label tag?

Comment: If it's just text, you can overwrite the label's content with `var target = document.getElementById("lbl1"); while (target.firstChild) { target.removeChild(target.firstChild); } target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common …

```
document.getElementById('lbl1').innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: thanks... i was trying this way.. document.getElementById(lbl1).text=str

Comment: @Ian method in the comments is best if just wanting text. See [Security Considerations of element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

```
function display() {
    var str="Hello World";
    var label = document.getElementById('lbl1');
    label.innerHTML = str;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("lbl1").innerHTML = display();` and add a return statement inside the function:

```
function display() 
{
   var str="Hello World";
   return str;
}
```

You edit the contents in a similar manner: `document.getElementById("lbl1").innerHTML = "New content...";`.

You could also modify your `display()` function a little bit to get the desired result:

```
function display() 
{
   var str="Hello World";
   var label = document.getElementById("lbl1");
   label.innerHTML = str;
}
```

Another way:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  var button = document.getElementById("btn1");
  button.onclick = function()
  {
    document.getElementById("lbl1").innerHTML = "Hello World";
  }
}
```

The last way is the most desired and it's the best to put JavaScript code inside another file and attach it via the `src` attribute of the `script` element.

Let's provide a complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <label id="lbl1">Label </label>
    <button id="btn1">Click </button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Then inside the JavaScript file you just register various events:

```
//JavaScript

window.onload = function() //You have to ensure that everything has loaded
{
  var button = document.getElementById("btn1");
  button.onclick = function()
  {
    document.getElementById("lbl1").innerHTML = "Hello World";
  }
}
```

It's generally considered the best way to register events in a separate JavaScript file because of performance and maintenance simplicity gains. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div>
    <label id="lbl1">Label </label>
    <button id="btn1" onclick="display()">Click </button>
    <script>
    function display() {
        var str="Hello World";
        var label = document.getElementById("lbl1");
        label.innerText = str;
    }
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

When you click the button, the function display() is run, and the label tag's text is changed to "Hello World".