# Auto-submit the prompt() pop up based on a timer

Tags: javascript, timer, submit, prompt

Ok, I may have found enough information that I should be able to put this together myself, but I just can't.

I'm trying (because reasons) to get string input from users by calling something like this:

var myVar = prompt("Some question?");

I want the prompt popup to automatically submit after, say, 30 seconds. Then I want the script to keep running. I want to use prompt because it's easy. Is there a way to auto submit that based on a timer?

I feel like the key might be somewhere in these two links:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
[Click a button every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515944/click-a-button-every-second)

Do I need to use a popup, not a prompt?
[Javascript popups: Submit form, show "wait" screen for 5 seconds, then auto-close popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392110/javascript-popups-submit-form-show-wait-screen-for-5-seconds-then-auto-clos)

Or do I need to use a form?
[Auto-Submit Form using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376173/auto-submit-form-using-javascript)

Thanks in advance for the help. New user here, and I don't think this question has been answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here's my answer:

1. Use jQuery
2. Use [Alertify](http://fabien-d.github.com/alertify.js/)
3. Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

These three things got me where I needed to be; hopefully someone else will eventually stumble on this and get some use out of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any kind of control over the behaviour of your prompt, besides just a means of basic text input, you will want to create your own prompt within a popup window or lightbox.  The built-in prompt does not have any kind of auto submit functionality.  It will not work in certain versions of Metro IE and has varying behaviour across different browsers (Safari).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: Do you have an example of a popup with autosubmit  functionality?