# Select List Manipulation

Tags: jquery, select

This question is similar to at least one other question, but the resolution didn't help me. I have some code that worked great in jQuery 1.4, but works no longer. I have two buttons that (used to) allow the user to navigate thru a select list. Here's the working version:

http://jsbin.com/weput/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="setOption(-1)">&#8592;</button>
<button onclick="setOption(1)">&#8594;</button>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function setOption(num) {
  var current = $( "#select1" ).attr( "selectedIndex" )
  var next = current + num;
  $('#select1 option:eq('+next+')').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

**What do I need to update to make it work in, say, jQuery 1.11.0?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The linked code seems to work for me in Firefox 28.0/OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: Works in Chrome -> Win 8.1

Comment: Does not work in 28.0 Win XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wakul/1/edit)**

Use `.prop()`

```
function setOption(num) {
  var current = $( "#select1" ).prop( "selectedIndex" );
  var next = current + num;
  $('#select1 option:eq('+next+')').prop('selected', true);
}
```

---

Try to **avoid using inline JS** cause hardly maintainable.
Use rather ID selectors like:

```
<button id="prevOption">&#8592;</button>
<button id="nextOption">&#8594;</button>
```

and this is all you need:

**[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsbin.com/wakul/2/edit)**

```
function setOption() {
  var num = this.id.match('prev') ? -1 : 1;
  var curr = $("#select1").prop("selectedIndex") + num;
  $('#select1 option:eq('+curr+')').prop('selected', true);
}

$('#prevOption, #nextOption').click( setOption );
```

Or also this code:

**[LIVE DEMO 3](http://jsbin.com/wakul/5/edit)**

```
$('#prevOption, #nextOption').click(function(){
  var n = this.id.match('prev')?-1:1;
  $('#select1').prop("selectedIndex", function(i,v){return v+n;});
});
```

Some good readings:
[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting
[When should I use Inline vs. External Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

```
<button id="a">&#8592;</button>
<button id="b">&#8594;</button>

<select id="select1">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

jquery 1.11.0

```
$(function() {
    $('#a').click(function(){
  var num = this.id.match('prev')+1;
  var curr = $("#select1").prop("selectedIndex") + num;
  $('#select1 option:eq('+curr+')').prop('selected', true);
    });
   $('#b').click(function(){
  var num = this.id.match('prev')-1;
  var curr = $("#select1").prop("selectedIndex") + num;
  $('#select1 option:eq('+curr+')').prop('selected', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: You really don't need all those repeated lines of code, it's too verbose and not the way we should do programming, for a cleaner solution take a look at my answer ;) also what is supposed this line to do `var num = this.id.match('prev')+1;` ? Also in the next click handler `var num = this.id.match('prev')-1;` ? To me seems like a bad copy-paste of my code actually. In your example `this.id.match('prev')` returns `null` and than you do some strange operations with it, also the *prev - next* are a bit inversed.

Comment: 5min after as I can see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23229092/revisions, but nevermind you did not answered my question. Why you use `this.id.match('prev')` ? What is `prev` in your code? I can only see these two buttons `<button id="a">&#8592;</button>
<button id="b">&#8594;</button>`