# how to show hidden i tag on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an li as below

```
<li class="active">
        <a href="#" onclick="editCategory(this)" class="active" value="14-client" id=""> qqqq
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right" style="display:none"></i></a>
    </li>
```

It has an i tag which is hidden at beginning  `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right" style="display:none"></i>`

I want to show this i tag only when mouse is clicked on the anchor tag so I wrote `onclick="editCategory(this)"`

and this is  my function

```
function editCategory(id)
    {
        alert('category');
        $(this).children().show();
    }
```

so when I click on the anchor tag then alert works `alert('category')` but the i tag is not shown.

Can anybody please point out the mistake I have done

Comment: Why you are using inline event handling ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha sorry did not understand

Comment: Why not using `document.ready(...)` ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha sorry I am poor in js/jquery.Is there any demerit of the way I am using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this. `<i>` is the child of your `<a>` tag. **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhZmP/3/)**

You are already passing `this` as a parameter to function `editCategory(id)` referenced by `id`.

```
function editCategory(id)
{
    alert('category');
    $(id).children('i').show();
}
```

Or

```
function editCategory(id)
{
    alert('category');
    $(id).find('i').show();
}
```

Other alternative,

```
$('i',id).show();
```

Comment: So if it is an issue of passing parameters , why replace children() by find and children('i').. Don't repeat my answer please . The main issue is param

Comment: I have some 15 li's.Now if I click on 1st li then i tag is shown.Now if I again click on the 2nd li then 1st as well as 2nd li is shown.Is it possible to remove all li except the current one

Comment: There can be many children to the `<a>` tag, So I used specific filter. And I did not repeat your answer. There are thousand there who use these selectors.

Comment: @JqueryLearner, you wish to remove rest of the `<li>` or `<i>` ?

Comment: Please Recheck, in my code only one `<i>` is shown - which we click. You can check in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54958/discussion-between-shaunakde-and-jquerylearner).

Comment: I have a doubt,can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

---

```
function editCategory(id)
{
    alert('category');
    $(id).find('i').show("100");
}
```

[### `DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/6MY8Y/3/)

---

Also You're Missing `$(document).ready(function(){...});` in your `javascript` if you're using `JQuery` be sure that it becomes ready as soon as your `DOM` becomes ready.

---

So I've changed your code as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // Here $(this) will be `document` object
   $(".active").click(function(){ 
      //alert('category');
      $(this).find('i').show("100");  // Now this refers to object from which event is bubbled or generated.
    }); 
});
```

and your `html` will be:

```
<a href="#" class="active" value="14-client" id="qqq"> qqqq
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right" style="display:none">aaa</i></a>
```

[### `DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/6MY8Y/2/)

I mean this is era of `JQuery` Man. and you're still using `inline-javascript`. just get rid of it.

---

Also In this code:

```
function editCategory(id)
{
    alert('category');
    console.log($(this)); //or try alert instead of console.log, it Will Log/alert Window Object 
    console.log($(id)); // This will log <a> Object.
    $(id).find('i').show("100");
}
```

you're passing `id` as object `this`(anchor obj) to function, and `$(this)`(the object you're acessing) is now refering (in your case) to `window` object.

[### `DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/6MY8Y/4/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again.well can you tell me why should not I use inline-javascript?

Comment: Sure. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript

Comment: This is my stackoverflow room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-and-jquery-beginners

Answer (score 1):

Try something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/bUtA3/1/) instead (Put this between `<head><script>...</script></head>`):

```
$(function(){
    $('a.active').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('i').show();
    });
});
```

Use this `HTML`:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#" class="active" value="14-client" id=""> qqqq
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right" style="display:none"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,+1.I have some 15 li's and I want to show that i whose a is clicked.Then will your answer will be useful?

Comment: Yes. it will still be useful

Comment: Yes, you need to declare only one event handler for all same elements.

Comment: There is nothing inside the `i` tag, check the updated answer's link.

Answer (score 0):

## It is an issue of parameter and not other thing : $(id) and not $(this)

```
function editCategory(id)
    {
        alert('category');
        $(id).children().show();
    }
```

`$(id)` and not `$(this)`

Because `$(this).children().show();` means the `this` of function and not `this` of `a` Tag .

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/bUtA3/

Comment: Can you please explain me why should not I use $this

Comment: Because you pass id as argument : editCategory(id) , which refers to this of a element .

Comment: I pass this as an argument and doesnt this refers to an object?

Comment: I have some 15 li's.Now if I click on 1st li then i tag is shown.Now if I again click on the 2nd li then 1st as well as 2nd li is shown.Is it possible to remove all li except the current one

Comment: All answers did not concentrate on main issue. Your issue is one and only one thing  .ok ?

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GnrVh/5/)**
  try this

```
$("li.active a.active").click(function() {
        $(this).find("i").show();

});
```