# change inline JS to external

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted to change this inline javascript at the bottom of my html to a external.js file.  It alter the image size depending if the mouse is on it or not.   I wanted to know if I had to change change the below code or if I were calling the css elements wrong.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    $('img').hover(function(){
        $(this).css({width:"100%",height:"100%"});
    },function(){
        $(this).css({width:"50%",height:"50%"});   
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

I want to thank everyone who down voted my question; as I beginner when I asked this question (still am), you made me feel warm and comfortable here and gave me lost of confidence.

Comment: copy the contents to the external file and then src it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have a separate file that you reference this way from your HTML document

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/file.js'></script>
```

That file would contain ONLY your actual code, ie this

```
$('img').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({width:"100%",height:"100%"});
},function(){
    $(this).css({width:"50%",height:"50%"});   
});
```

You also might need to put your javascript inside a document ready call -

```
$(function(){
  $('img').hover(function(){
      $(this).css({width:"100%",height:"100%"});
  },function(){
      $(this).css({width:"50%",height:"50%"});   
  });
});
```

Other resources

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/91242/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-javascript-file-using-script-tag
- [When should I use Inline vs. External Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript)
- http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: This is not working for me. Could the fact that this is inside a php file be breaking it?

Comment: Make sure that you're referencing the path to your js file correctly.
You also might need to put your javascript inside a document ready call. Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your script looks fine. To include it from an external file you just need to create a new `.js` file containing just the text between the `<script>` tags... and include it like this:

```
<script src="path/file.js">
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Could the fact that this is inside a php file be breaking it?

Comment: @user2613088 so long as you include this file after you have loaded jQuery it should work fine. If not, place your script into a `ready` event like this: `$(document).ready(function () {   //your script here  });`

Answer (score 1):

Its fine, you can move it to its own file without a problem, then replace the script tag with this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/external/js" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add "$(document).ready(function(){" and it started working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(function(){
        $(this).css({width:"100%",height:"100%"});
    },function(){
        $(this).css({width:"50px",height:"50px"});   
    });
});`
```