# is it better to embed scripts in html or have them in a separate file?

Tags: html

I need to know the benefits of doing it either way, specifically which loads the script faster, and which is easier to edit if something goes wrong.

Comment: Google will provide you with the answer.

Comment: Simply Web performance really matters ! 99% times it will give you faster end-user response times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use Inline vs. External Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**Advantages for external js file**

It separates HTML and code

It makes HTML and JavaScript easier to read and maintain

Cached JavaScript files can speed up page loads

Answer (score 0):

Using separated files, the browser can cache files like css and javascript. 
Use separated files. 
To speedup performance read about CDN (Content Delivery Network). 
Tks.