# Is it better to have a single .js file or copy the script in every page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a website which uses three, identical JavaScript functions in a lot of HTML pages.
Is it better to link all the pages to a single .js file or copying the script to every HTML page which uses it?

Comment: It is always better to add script file instead of adding whole code on every page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some advantages and disadvantages for embedding JavaScript in HTML or saving it externally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707187/what-are-some-advantages-and-disadvantages-for-embedding-javascript-in-html-or-s)

Comment: Split it up so each page only has to load two scripts, the one containing the shared functions that you can use in each page and the one for that page specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend putting the script into a separate file and link to it. If you want to make changes to the code, you only have to do it once. **=> Removing redundancy**. On the other hand, you reduce the amount of requests to the webserver, because each script tag will create an extra GET request. But I gladly pay this price for low redundancy!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use one file and link to it.

But if the functions are pretty small google will be happy if you put them in the footer of your page directly above the body tag. I would do this only if you use a template where you have one footer for all pages and don't need to edit every single page.